# How to do a cross join partitioned by a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to have a cartesian product between two columns. Here is the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE CART (
MYSK NUMBER, 
MYPROD VARCHAR(50 CHAR),
CUST VARCHAR(50 CHAR)
)
;
INSERT INTO CART (MYSK, MYPROD, CUST)
VALUES('1', 'A', 'Jim');
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO CART (MYSK, MYPROD, CUST)
VALUES('2', 'B', 'Jim');
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO CART (MYSK, MYPROD, CUST)
VALUES('4', 'A', 'Jack');
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO CART (MYSK, MYPROD, CUST)
VALUES('5', 'B', 'Jack');
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO CART (MYSK, MYPROD, CUST)
VALUES('7', 'C', 'Jack');
COMMIT;
```

How can I do a cross join between columns MYSK ja MYPROD so that cross join only applies within column CUST, not for all rows? This produces a wrong result:

```
SELECT AA.MYSK, BB.MYPROD, BB.CUST
FROM CART AA 
CROSS JOIN CART BB
;
```

Correct result set is this:

```
+------+--------+------+
| MYSK | MYPROD | CUST |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | A      | Jim  |
|    2 | A      | Jim  |
|    1 | B      | Jim  |
|    2 | B      | Jim  |
|    4 | A      | Jack |
|    5 | A      | Jack |
|    7 | A      | Jack |
|    4 | B      | Jack |
|    5 | B      | Jack |
|    7 | B      | Jack |
|    4 | C      | Jack |
|    5 | C      | Jack |
|    7 | C      | Jack |
+------+--------+------+
```

Comment: I'm very curious about the use case for this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `join`.  Try this:

```
SELECT AA.MYSK, BB.MYPROD, BB.CUST
FROM CART AA JOIN
     CART BB
     ON AA.CUST = BB.CUST;
```